# Dotnet core api hangs on Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: asp.net-core, .net-core, ubuntu-20.04

I have built an Asp.net core API and when I started developing it on a **Linux ubuntu 20.4** the app just froze without even throwing any exception
here is my code

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;

namespace passman.core
{
    public class DbInitializer
    {
        public static async Task SeedUser(UserManager<ApplicationUser> userManager)
        {
            try
            {
                var systemUser = await userManager.FindByNameAsync("system");
                if (systemUser == null)
                {
                    systemUser = new ApplicationUser
                    {
                        DateOfBirth = DateTime.Now,
                        Email = "system@domain.com",
                        UserName = "system",
                        FullName = "Sys Admin"
                    };
                    await userManager.CreateAsync(systemUser, "ABCD1230@abcd");
                }
            }
            catch (Exception exception)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(exception);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

when debuggingn the app the execution freezes once reached this statement `var systemUser = await userManager.FindByNameAsync("system");`

which is obviously calling the database I'm using Identity for Authentication/Authorization but this happens when executing any query to the Database.

But what makes it weird the same code run the previous version of Ubuntu LTS 18.04 and tested on Manjaro 20.0.3 and Windows 10 it works as expected.

Ubuntu 20.04
[image: Execution Ubuntu 20.04]
[image: SDK Information]

Manjaro 20.0.3
[image: Execution]
[image]

Windows 10
[image]
[image]

Database Information:

```
Microsoft SQL Server 2016 (SP1-GDR) (KB4505219) - 13.0.4259.0 (X64) 
 Jun 15 2019 19:20:12 
 Copyright (c) Microsoft Corporation
 Enterprise Edition (64-bit) on Windows Server 2012 R2 Standard 6.3 <X64> (Build 9600: ) (Hypervisor)
```

Comment: Do you have DB on the same host?

Comment: no, it is remote but all three os are on the same network they can reach the DB server

Comment: You can check the DB connection logs probably, whether connection was made or not. Maybe something was changed in the latest version of ubuntu. And try to to update the .NET Core to the latest version

Comment: I just upgraded my DB server to 2017 now it is working may be a bug with 2016

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Upgraded my `SQL server` from 2016 to 2017 now it is working may be a bug with `dotnet core` on `Ubuntu 20.04`